# how to access commandline parameter in a crawlspider in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to pass a parameter in `scrapy crawl ...` command line to be used in the rule definition in the extended [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.12/experimental/crawlspider-v2.html#crawlspider-v2), like the following

```
name = 'example.com'
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

rules = (
    # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
    # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

    # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
)
```

I want that the allow attribute in the [SgmlLinkExtractor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#sgmllinkextractor) is specified in the command line parameter.
I have googled and found that I can get the parameter value in the spider's `__init__` method, but how can I get the parameter in the command line to be used in the Rule definition?

Answer (score 5):

You can build your Spider's `rules` attribute in the `__init__` method, something like:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def __init__(self, allow=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(self.allow,),)),
        )
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And you pass the `allow` attribute on the command line like this:

```
scrapy crawl example.com -a allow="item\.php"
```